# What determines the amount of calls in this code

Tags: java

What determines the amount of calls it takes for the aMap size to be 0 in the code below? I've ran this a few times and while it takes only a few calls sometimes, other times, it takes hundreds.

```
public class App{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    WeakHashMap<Employee, EmployeeVal> aMap = new WeakHashMap<Employee, EmployeeVal>();

    Employee emp = new Employee("Vinoth");
    EmployeeVal  val = new EmployeeVal("Programmer");

    aMap.put(emp, val);

    emp = null;
    System.gc();
    int count = 0;
    while(0 != aMap.size()){
        ++count;
        System.gc();
    }
    System.out.println("Took " + count + " calls to the System.gc() to result in weakHashMap size of: " + aMap.size());
  }
}
```

Comment: Really? `aMap` doesn't ever reduce it's size here. The count increments to two and stops.

Comment: aMap size outputs 1 before the while loop. In the while loop, the count is different every time I run the code.

Comment: `Employee` and `EmployeeVal` are undefined. Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here.

Comment: Clarification ~ increments `to one` then stops. ( not to `two' )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared aMap as type `WeakHashMap`.

Also, you are calling `System.gc()`.
A `WeakHashMap`.

First: A call to System.gc() does not guarantee garbage collection will occur immediately. It is only a suggestion to the garbage collector that you would 'like' gc to run.

Secondly: From the documentation on WeakHashMap:

> Hash table based implementation of the Map interface, with weak keys. An entry in a WeakHashMap will automatically be removed when its key is no longer in ordinary use. More precisely, the presence of a mapping for a given key will not prevent the key from being discarded by the garbage collector, that is, made finalizable, finalized, and then reclaimed. When a key has been discarded its entry is effectively removed from the map, so this class behaves somewhat differently from other Map implementations.

So, immediately after you added emp to the aMap, you set emp to null.
Therefore, emp and the entry in the map is no longer referenced and can be gc'd.
But, remember that when exactly the gc occurs is not deterministic and not guaranteed.

Comment: Thank you! very helpful.